# ConfigurationHostSettings is internal

Tags: masstransit

I want to bind host options from `appsettings.json` file using `IConfiguration.GetSection(...).Get<ConfigurationHostSettings>()`.

`IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator.Host` has overload for that, but `ConfigurationHostSettings` is internal

Use fluent interfacecs when configuring MassTransit from configuration file is a pain =/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ASP.NET Core configuration, you should create your own class that has the settings you want to configure via `appsettings.json` and use that to configure the host in MassTransit.

If your configuration class implements the correct interface, you should be able to pass it directly so that MassTransit can get the appropriate host settings.